# How to get the site name during plugin development?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing my first wordpress plugin, and i need to get the site name.

The [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_site) says to use `get_current_site_name( $current_site )` function.

Here is my script

**myPlugin.php:**

```
$site_data = get_current_site_name( $current_site );
```

but get_current_site_name() function is not defined yet.

Also there is no global `$current_site` variable, as written in documentation.

I also try to add a wp_loaded action, to let the wordpress load fully, but it doesn't help.

```
function myfunction() {
     global $current_site;
     $site_data = get_current_site_name( $current_site );
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'myfunction');

//Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_current_site_name() in ...
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**Update:**

There is a bug in this site, when i try to write **hello** at the top of my question, it strips it automatically. So i'm writing it here - Hello guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function is only available in [network mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). It will return the name of the site (the one you use when you create the site), **not the title that you set in the options**.

You probably want to use [`get_bloginfo('name')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/.Function_Reference/get_bloginfo). This one returns the site title. Yeah I know, inconsistent naming, global variables ...it's WP :)

Comment: I spent about an hour searching this :/ Thank you man.
Maybe you know how to get registered user name ?