# How to get user information during plugin development?

Tags: php, wordpress

I asked a question about getting a wordpress site title [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823863/how-to-get-the-site-name-during-plugin-development).

Also i need to get the user information, but **NOTHING** from documentation doesn,t work if i do not use network mode but developing a plugin. So i can not use `wp_get_current_user()` or `is_user_logged_in()` or `get_userdata()`.

I can't find documentation about this.

Could you please tell me how can i check if user registered, and if yes, get it's username and realname. Or give me the link to appropriate documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried <?php get_userdata( $userid ); ?>

Comment: No. is $userid a global variable in wordpress ?

Comment: $userid
(integer) (required) The ID of the user whose data should be retrieved.
Default: None  Source->http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Comment: I got Call to undefined function get_userdata() in ...

Comment: make sure you have get_header() and get_footer() in your page, let me test it a bit more and I'll get back

Comment: I do not have get_header() because i'm implementing a plugin.

Comment: I would think you'd still need to pull in the core dependencies, no?

Comment: No. As documentation says - get_header() Includes the header.php template file from your current theme's directory. I do not need this.

Comment: [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85492/12615) may speed up your plugin development.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the user id (int) parameter and it works like a charm.

```
<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
  echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User level: ' . $user_info->user_level . "\n";
  echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";
```

Source -> For more info

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Comment: Ok, but how can i get a user id ?

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out from your perspective but it's almost impossible for me to test, I would try this -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo -> this also seems to need the wp-includes

Comment: I found the solution. I posted the answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

If i use wp_loaded action, to let the wordpress load fully, it works,

```
function myfunction() {
      global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
      echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
      echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
      echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'myfunction');
...
```